# Tracker (Accelerometer, gyroscope) Development Adnroid

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, accelerometer, tracker

I need help/guidance on where to start for making an application that gets the accelerometer data from a tracker such as a smartwatch and process it on the smartphone.

My questions are:

1. I'm looking for a tracker that captures acceleration data; are there any free-source designs out there? Or some gadget type devices that are easy and free to program.
2. What other hardware or software would be needed to get this data to an android smartphone?

Can you please point as to where should I start from?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need additional device. You can use built in accelerometer to get the data.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion